# Steelseries arctis 5 only properly detected on reboot

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 and recently got a Steelseries Arctis 5 headset. If I plug it in, most of the time either the digital output option is missing, or the microphone is missing. If I reboot, it gets detected properly though, but rebooting everytime I want to use the headset is not really ideal ofcourse.

Anybody have an idea what could be going on here and how to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/DemonTPx/steelseries-arctis-5-pulseaudio-profile

Comment: I know about that one, it is already included in my version of pulseaudio. If I try to install the deb it says "trying to overwrite '/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/steelseries-arctis-5-output-chat.conf', which is also in package pulseaudio 1:12.2-2ubuntu3"

Comment: I will try with force overwrite (--force-overwrite)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed force installing the deb package from https://github.com/DemonTPx/steelseries-arctis-5-pulseaudio-profile did the trick it seems, thank you @Rinzwind